# Center Align Panel Header - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My panel header is not center align

[image]

I can reproduce it here.
https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/7zd83tr9/

How do I center align it?

```html
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-for="(item,i) in 5"
    :key="i"
  >
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
       <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col> AAA </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-icon color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="right">
          <v-btn text color="red" @click.stop="remove(index, type)">
            DELETE
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    
    
    
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `align-center` helper class on the `v-row` element.

```
class="align-center"
```

**Snippet**:

```html
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-for="(item,i) in 5"
    :key="i"
  >
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
       <v-row no-gutters class="align-center">
        <v-col> AAA </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-icon color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="right">
          <v-btn text color="red" @click.stop="remove(index, type)">
            DELETE
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

**Example**: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/poLeWXb/dcb97f5a9ea97d1c2476b6437b91714f

**Vuetify Docs**: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-align